# java kryonet - ChatMessage - Class is not registered

Tags: java, tcp, network-programming, kryo, kryonet

i just started to use kryonet.

the chat example works fine when run from the examples folder.

if i copy the chat client, server, and network files into another source folder in eclipse, i get IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.examples.chat.Network$RegisterName (please see below).

i added printouts around the: "kryo.register(ChatMessage.class);", so i know that this is being called.

the client hangs trying to connect.

any pointers will be appreciated.

thanks

```
00:05  INFO: [kryonet] Connecting: localhost/127.0.0.1:22222
00:05 DEBUG: [kryonet] Port 59450/TCP connected to: localhost/127.0.0.1:22222
00:05 DEBUG: [kryo] Read: RegisterTCP
00:05  INFO: [kryonet] Connection 1 connected: localhost/127.0.0.1
Exception in thread "Client" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.examples.chat.Network$RegisterName
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.examples.chat.Network$RegisterName.class);
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:461)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.writeClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:79)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClass(Kryo.java:491)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:596)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.KryoSerialization.write(KryoSerialization.java:66)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.TcpConnection.send(TcpConnection.java:210)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection.sendTCP(Connection.java:87)
    at com.tayek.kryo.ChatClient$1.connected(ChatClient.java:55)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection.notifyConnected(Connection.java:242)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.update(Client.java:284)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client.run(Client.java:356)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "Client" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.examples.chat.Network$RegisterName
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.examples.chat.Network$RegisterName.class);
```

The stack trace says that `Network$RegisterName` class is not registered.

Register this class and your project will start working as normal.